# Errors in using Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, centos

//Edited as the previous error is gone

I have replaced ppclinux library to a specific library. New Error appeared as-

```
libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_49.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../../ThirdPartyLibs/boost/stage/lib/libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_49.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libAFE.so] Error 1
```

Any solution on that?

Comment: libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_49.*ppclinux*.a should give you a hint.

Comment: I am new in this platform. Where to find the hint. Will elaborate?

Comment: Unless this is a PPC (PowerPC) Linux distro, then you're trying to link to the wrong architecture. I expect you want x86 or x86-64.

Comment: yes exactly. I want X86_64. What should I do now?

Comment: I have replaced ppclinux library to a specific library. New Error appeared as-

    libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_49.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    ../../ThirdPartyLibs/boost/stage/lib/libboost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_49.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [libAFE.so] Error 1


Any solution on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was that the libraries were built in 64 bit. Configuring bjam command solved it. The command is as follows-

```
bjam toolset=gcc address-model=64 architecture=x86 variant=release link=static,shared --layout=versioned --build-type=complete
```